# adding yaml content using yq to a yaml attribute

Tags: json, parsing, yaml, yq

I want to add new array entry to the providers field in in.yaml:

```
providers:
  - name: providerName
    envoyExtAuthzGrpc:
      service: sbm-grpc.local
      port: 50054
```

I have a temporary file ext.yaml.

```
authProvider:
  name: sbm-ext-authz 
  envoyExtAuthzGrpc:
    service: sbm-grpc.local
    port: 50054
```

My test code:

```
...

providerName=$service.m-ext-authz
serviceName=$service.m-grpc.local
port=50054

o="$(yq e '.authProvider' ext.yaml | yq e '.name="providerName"' -)" yq e -i '.providers += strenv(o)' in.yaml
```

The output is:

```
providers:
  - |-
    name: providerName
    envoyExtAuthzGrpc:
      service: sbm-grpc.local
      port: 50054
```

But should be:

```
providers:
  - name: providerName
    envoyExtAuthzGrpc:
      service: sbm-grpc.local
      port: 50054
```

Is there a way to supress the |- not to treat the content as a string and suppress the linebreaks?

Answer (score 0):

Using `env` instead of `strenv` will prevent it from being interpreted as string:

```sh
o="$(yq e '.authProvider | .name="providerName"' ext.yaml)" \
  yq e '.providers += env(o)' in.yaml
```